# Pig-script не записывает данные в хадуп

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Вопрос обозначен в заголовке. Причина не ясна. Привожу пример скрипта:

```
SET mapred.job.queue.name 'data_mining';
SET mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent 5;

raw = LOAD 'hbase://xxx' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('info:urlN') AS (urlN:chararray);
STORE raw INTO 'links' USING PigStorage ('\t');
```

Также приведу лог:

> HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt
>   Features
>   2.6.0-cdh5.4.1  0.12.0-cdh5.4.1 urvanov 2018-08-03 22:45:56     2018-08-04 05:15:58     UNKNOWN
>
> Success!
>
> Job Stats (time in seconds): JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime
>   MinMapTIme      AvgMapTime      MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime
>   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime        Alias
>   Feature Outputs job_1517304584149_185731        2690    0       20492 
>   3840    8674    8661    n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     raw
>   MAP_ONLY        hdfs://ix-jupiter/user/urvanov/collection_1,
>
> Input(s): Successfully read 246642204846 records (1137790 bytes) from:
>   "hbase://collection_1"
>
> Output(s): Successfully stored 246642204846 records (29915201763044
>   bytes) in: "hdfs://ix-jupiter/user/urvanov/collection_1"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 246642204846 Total bytes written :
>   29915201763044 Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags
>   proactively spilled: 0 Total records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_1517304584149_185731
>
> 2018-08-04 05:15:59,998 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is
>   completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job
>   history server 2018-08-04 05:16:00,921 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы как таковой нет. Она связана с тем, что в хадупе, после выполнения pig-скрипта и записи данных в hdfs, размер почему-то не указывается для вложенных директорий (всегда ли так, я не знаю). В данном случае, `links` и `links_time` весят 1tb и 9tb. Но их размер не указан. Это меня ввело в заблуждение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]